# Gridview Column Resize issue with updatepanel

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to auto resize column feature for asp.net gridview. I am using colResizable-1.3.min.js
for column resize functionality and its working fine. but when i tried to add gridview with update panel then jquery does not work. its just working on postback request.

Thanks

Comment: if any one want demo code so i can give you.. thanks

Comment: i found solution thanks...

Answer (score 0):

```
   <script>
   //On Page Load
        $(function () {
             $('#<%=gvInv_ReceiveVoucherItem.ClientID %>').colResizable({
                liveDrag: true,
                gripInnerHtml: "<div class='grip'></div>",
                draggingClass: "dragging",
                postbackSafe: true,
                partialRefresh: true              
        });
        });

    //On UpdatePanel Refresh
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    if (prm != null) {
        prm.add_endRequest(function (sender, e) {
            if (sender._postBackSettings.panelsToUpdate != null) {
                $('#<%=gvInv_ReceiveVoucherItem.ClientID %>').colResizable({
                    liveDrag: true,
                    gripInnerHtml: "<div class='grip'></div>",
                    draggingClass: "dragging",
                    postbackSafe: true,
                    partialRefresh: true
                });
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

```
      </Columns>                             
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Please, correct the format / indentation of your code and comment it.